# Why would you use an Action Creator callback function over using a simple object?

Tags: javascript, object, redux, callback

I'm currently learning Redux on codecademy and encountered something that feels redundant.

The course gives the following example on excessive ways to call dispatches:

```
store.dispatch({type:'toggle'});
store.dispatch({type:'toggle'});
store.dispatch({type:'toggle'});
```

> In most Redux applications, action creators are used to reduce this repetition and to provide consistency. An action creator is simply a function that returns an action object with a type property. They are typically called and passed directly to the store.dispatch() method resulting in fewer errors and an easier-to-read dispatch statement.

> The above code could be rewritten using an action creator called toggle() like so:

```
const toggle = () => {
  return { type: "toggle" };
}
store.dispatch(toggle()); // Toggles the light to 'off'
store.dispatch(toggle()); // Toggles the light back to 'on'
store.dispatch(toggle()); // Toggles the light back to 'off'
```

My question is, why not simplify this Action Creator callback function that returns an object, by just creating an object like so?

```
const toggle = { type: toggle }
store.dispatch(toggle);
store.dispatch(toggle);
store.dispatch(toggle);
```

Comment: I don't use Redux, but it's likely down to state change.  eg.  `toggle === toggle` will evaluate to `true`, but `toggle() === toggle()` will evaluate to `false`..  IOW: mutability v immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const toggle = Object.freeze({ type: "toggle" })` does indeed work fine and would be appropriate for this particular action. However, often an action does carry a payload, and to create actions with different payload values a function would be used, e.g.

```
function openSection(index) {
    return {type: "open", index};
}
```

that you would call like

```
store.dispatch(openSection(1))
// or
e => store.dispatch(openSection(+e.target.dataset.index))
```

Also this will allow you to later [add side effects to the action creator](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#how-can-i-represent-side-effects-such-as-ajax-calls-why-do-we-need-things-like-action-creators-thunks-and-middleware-to-do-async-behavior) without having to refactor the code that uses the action.